# How can I pass arguments from an outer function to an inner function using parLapply

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am trying to create an R function that does a parallelized bootstrapping routine, but am having difficulties passing the the function arguments within parLapply. 
Below is a (hopefully) reproducible example, where the cluster is unable to find the values for the arguments:

```
innerFun <- function(a=rnorm(10), q=0.5){
  quantile(a, probs = q)
}

library(parallel)
bootFun <- function(a=rnorm(10), q=0.5, nperm=10, no_cores = detectCores() - 1){

  parFun <- function(x){
    set.seed(x)
    ai <- sample(a, size=length(a), replace = TRUE)
    return(innerFun(a=ai, q=q))
  }

  ARGS <- list("innerFun", "a", "q", "nperm")

  cl <- parallel::makeCluster(no_cores, type="PSOCK")
  nn <- split(1:nperm, 1:nperm)
  parallel::clusterExport(cl, varlist = ARGS)
  res <- parallel::parLapply(cl, nn, parFun)
  parallel::stopCluster(cl)

  res <- do.call("rbind", res)
  return(res)

}

set.seed(1)
res1 <- bootFun(a=rnorm(100), q=0.5, nperm=10, no_cores = detectCores() - 1)
# Error in get(name, envir = envir) : object 'a' not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the trickier aspects of `parallel::clusterExport`. As it says in the docs,

`clusterExport assigns the values on the master R process of the variables named in varlist to variables of the same names in the global environment (aka ‘workspace’) of each node`

That is, it looks in the global environment for the variable names. The default `environment` argument also demonstrates this

`clusterExport(cl = NULL, varlist, envir = .GlobalEnv)`

You need to specify the environment to the function (non-global) environment like so

```
clusterExport(cl, args, env = environment())
```

In your case, update to

```
parallel::clusterExport(cl, varlist = ARGS, env = environment())
```

Replacing with the updated version, this leads to the output for `res1`

```
           50%
1   0.11379733
2  -0.01619026
3   0.05117174
4  -0.11234621
5   0.37001881
6   0.07445315
7   0.01455376
8  -0.03924000
9   0.01481569
10  0.18364332
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks so much.